# How to make bar charts for columns of a dataframe all at once?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have several catigorical and numeric features in a pandas data frame.
For the numeric features I was able to plot several histograms at once, using this code: (the data was downloaded from kaggle).

```
%matplotlib inline

axarr = temp.hist(bins=45, figsize=(20, 15))  # histograms of dataframe variables. Pick number of bins!
xlbl = ['Age [$Years$]', 'fnlwgt', 'capital_gain[$dollars$]','capital_loss [$dollars$]', 
        'hours_per_week']

for idx, ax in enumerate(axarr.flatten()):
    ax.set_xlabel(xlbl[idx])
    ax.set_ylabel("Count")
    
plt.show()
```

Now I'm trying to do the same for the catigorical values (bar plots), using thise code:

```
xlbl = ['workclass', 'education', 'educational-num','marital-status', 'occupation', 'relationship', 'race',
       'gender', 'native_country', 'income']
BARplt = sns.displot(data=temp2);

for idx, ax in enumerate(BARplt.flatten()):
    ax.set_xlabel(xlbl[idx])
    ax.set_ylabel("Count")
    
plt.show()
```

This is producing an error:

```
----> 7 for idx, ax in enumerate(BARplt.flatten()):
      8     ax.set_xlabel(xlbl[idx])
      9     ax.set_ylabel("Count")

AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'flatten'
```

and at the same time, it shows the barplot of the `educational-num` variable.

**NOTE**: numeric and catigorical features and were separated. numeric in `temp` df and catogirical in `temp2` df.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try `for idx, ax in enumerate(BARplt.axes[0])`

Comment: Or `for lbl, ax in zip(xlbl, BARplt.axes[0])`, `ax.set_xlabel(lbl)`

Comment: @BigBen both of those options still show only one bar plot.

Comment: It should be `BARplt.axes.flat`